# Android: Layer-List not working?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I am trying to put two oval drawables on top of each other, the first has transparency. However with the way I have it, it displays the first oval's color at the size of the second oval.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <size android:width="15dp" android:height="15dp" />
        <solid android:color="#35000000"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <size android:width="5dp" android:height="5dp" />
        <solid android:color="#000000"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

How can I get this to work as intended?

**EDIT:**
Here is the parent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/my_layerlist" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your XML code is correctly set up. The issue here may be the "parent" view hosting the layer-list. Can you post the code that includes the layer-list?

Comment: I posted the ImageView I am using. I have also tried setting it for a Button background

Comment: Have you tried using an explicit width for the ImageView (i.e. 15-20 dp?

Comment: Also, Have you tried separating the Drawables and drawing them independently to make sure they work independently? Mind you, you shouldn't have to, but these are just debugging steps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After doing much research on the different types of XML drawables, it appears that your `LayerDrawable` (layer-list) is be scaling the `ShapeDrawables` independently. ***Then***, the `ImageView` is scaling the `LayerDrawable`. According to [this guide from Google](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html), scaling for ***both*** `ShapeDrawable`s and `LayerDrawable`s is a concern. `LayerDrawable`s will check for necessary scaling on *each* item you have. They have several solutions:

- Set the `gravity` to something that does not scale, such as "center".
- define the drawable as a bitmap.
- Set the ImageView to scaleType that does not scale.

There is two major problem with this, however... You can only use `gravity` for the `bitmap`. And you cannot use a ShapeDrawable for the `bitmap` in XML. I tried ***everything*** I could think of to get it right. Here's the **only** thing that fixed it for me.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/oval1"
    android:scaleType="center"  />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/oval2"
    android:scaleType="center"  />
</FrameLayout>
```

So: I removed the LayerDrawable, separated the Shapes into their own XMLs, made two ImageViews. (for ease I stuck them in a FrameLayout). This was the only way to stop the scaling.

---

#### Testing Procedure

Tested in Android 2.1, 3.0, 4.0

- Changed Image `scaleType`
- Changed Image `width` and `height`
- Separated ShapeDrawables
- Changed LayerList to just `item`s with `drawable` attribute referencing separated `shape`s
- Changed LayerList to `bitmap`s referencing separated `shape`s.
- Changed order of `shape`s

---

Alternatively, you could do it in code.

---

- **Reference:** [Drawable Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html)

Comment: Thanks! Suggestion to test with `scaleType` in `ImageView` resolve my problem with layer-list drawable.